# Java Array printing 0

Tags: java, arrays

In the program if I enter 0 it exits, the problem is when I am trying to print the array afterwards there will be alot of 0 if I choose to exit. How do I prevent that being print.

```
package lu.ics.Sohail.labbar;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class November2012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tal;
        int summa=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] array = new int [100];
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i=0 ; i<array.length; i++ ){
            System.out.print("Ange tal 0 avsluta");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            summa =summa+array[i];
            if (array[i]==0) {
                break;
            }
            while(array[i]<min)
            { 
                min=array[i];
            }
            while(array[i]>max)
            { 
                max=array[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Talen är " + Arrays.toString(array));    
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Summan är " + summa);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Max är " + max);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Min är " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `List` not an array.

Comment: I don't even understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You don't want to print 0 from the array??? your question is not clear enough

Comment: no I do not. because the Array consist of 100 integers and if I print 0 , the for loop will exit. and if I print whatever is in the array it might be 1 , 2 ,3 ,4 and a bunch of 0s those are the ones I want to eliminate

Comment: Thomas got it.. Use List<Integer>

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand now.

`int [] array = new int [100];` will create an array of 100 ints and each element is initialized with the value 0 (that's the default for `int`). Thus when you print your array, 100 numbers will be printed, regardless of whether they are 0 or not.

You have a few options here:

- Use a `List<Integer>`, that way the list only contains numbers that were entered before the first 0.
- Print in a loop and break at the first 0 or at the end of the array.
- Optionally you might want to keep count of how many numbers have been entered, e.g. for calculating an average etc. This could be used to iterate over those first n elements in the array.

That being said, I'd suggest using lists, since this will be more flexible.

Comment: he got it.. As suggested use List<Integer>, instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the array has been initialised to 0 for each item in this call:

`int [] array = new int [100];`

And then when the first `0` is detected it breaks the `for` loop and prints everything.

Comment: can I prevent those remaining 0s to be printed

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the array with your own size. While creating your array 100 static memory allocated and all values are assigned to 0.

```
 System.out.print("Enter the array size");
 int arraySize = input.nextInt();
 int [] array = new int [arraySize];
```

Otherwise use  `ArrayList<Integer>` to store the numbers

Comment: well it has to be 100 , and I can terminate by entering 0 , all the other 0 will be printed

Answer (score -1):

Using ingeter array. But this will print null when you print the array. Add a condition to not do so while printing.

```
package com.prasad.samples.views;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class November2012 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tal;
        int summa=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer [] array = new Integer [100];
        System.out.println(array[0]);
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int max = 0;

        for (int i=0 ; i<array.length; i++ ){
            System.out.print("Ange tal 0 avsluta");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
            summa =summa+array[i];
            if (array[i]==0) {
                break;
            }
            while(array[i]<min)
            { 
                min=array[i];
            }
            while(array[i]>max)
            { 
                max=array[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.print("ar " + Arrays.toString(array));    
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("summan ar " + summa);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Max ar " + max);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Min ar " + min);
    }
}
```